# write output in new file using buffer writter

Tags: file, stream, filestream, streamwriter, filewriter

Output of this program I want to write in new file.so how can I generate new file like xls. or  other and write the results in it.
I had already read the file then applied kmean clustering algorithm and generate output now I want to write that.

```
 package kmean;
    //package greenblocks.statistics;

    import java.io.IOException;



    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;

    import weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans;
    import weka.core.Instances;

    /**
     *
     * @author admin
     */
    public class Kmean {

            public static BufferedReader readDataFile(String filename) {
            BufferedReader inputReader = null;

            try {
                inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.err.println("File not found: " + filename);
            }

            return inputReader;
        }


        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

            SimpleKMeans kmeans = new SimpleKMeans();

            kmeans.setSeed(10);

            //important parameter to set: preserver order, number of cluster.
            kmeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
            kmeans.setNumClusters(5);

            BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("elecNormNew.arff"); 
                   // BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("perturbed.csv"); 
            Instances data = new Instances(datafile);


            kmeans.buildClusterer(data);

            // This array returns the cluster number (starting with 0) for each instance
            // The array has as many elements as the number of instances
            int[] assignments = kmeans.getAssignments();

            int i=0;
            for(int clusterNum : assignments) {
                System.out.printf("Instance %d -> Cluster %d \n", i, clusterNum);
                i++;
            }

            // TODO code application logic here
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: actually I want to write the output of 'inputreader'' in newly generated other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to write your output in new text file... may this will help you

package com.mkyong;

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFileExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        String content = "This is the content to write into file";

        File file = new File("/filePath/filename.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   }
```